# Properly Testing a simple class with Private Methods

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

**Description:**
I have a simple class that creates a symlink to a directory of uploaded files that are only available to registered members. It uses the current users session id in order to generate the random directory for the user. Once the user logs out, the symlink is removed. I would like to unit test the functionality of the class.

**Question:**
How do I go about properly unit testing this class since most functions are private, and I don't see any reason to make them public?

Here is the code for the PHP class:

```
<?php

namespace Test\BackEnd\MemberBundle\Library;


use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface;

class DirectoryProtector
{
/** @var SessionInterface $_session */
private $_session;

/** @var ContainerInterface $_kernel */
private $_kernel;

/**
 * @param SessionInterface $session
 * @param KernelInterface $kernel
 */
public function __construct( SessionInterface $session, KernelInterface $kernel )
{
    $this->_session = $session;
    $this->_kernel = $kernel;
}

/**
 * @param bool|false $protect
 * Public method to symlink directories
 */
public function protectDirectory($protect = FALSE)
{

    if ($protect) {
        if ( ! $this->doesDirectoryExists())
            symlink($this->getAppDir() . '/uploads', $this->getViewableSessionDirectory());
    } else {
        if ($this->doesDirectoryExists())
            unlink($this->getViewableSessionDirectory());
    }

}

/**
 * @return bool
 * Check to see if viewable session directory exists or not
 */
private function doesDirectoryExists()
{
    if (file_exists($this->getViewableSessionDirectory()))
        return TRUE;

    return FALSE;
}

/**
 * @return string
 * Get viewable session full directory path
 */
private function getViewableSessionDirectory()
{
    return $this->getAppDir() . '/../web/files/' . $this->getSessionId();
}

/**
 * @return string
 * Return app root directory
 */
private function getAppDir()
{
    return $this->_kernel->getRootDir();
}

/**
 * @return string
 * Return session id
 */
private function getSessionId()
{
    return $this->_session->getId();
}

}
```

Here is the code for the current test class:

```
<?php

namespace Test\BackEnd\MemberBundle\Tests\Library;

use Test\BackEnd\MemberBundle\Library\DirectoryProtector;

class DirectoryProtectorTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

public function testProtectDirectory()
{
    //$this->markTestIncomplete("WIP on protect directory.");
    $request = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\SessionInterface')
        ->getMock();

    $container = $this->getMockBuilder('Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface')
        ->getMock();

    /** @var DirectoryProtector $dp */
    $dp = $this->getMockBuilder('Test\BackEnd\MemberBundle\Library\DirectoryProtector')
            ->setConstructorArgs(array($request, $container))
            ->setMethods(array(
                'getViewableSessionDirectory',
                'getAppDir',
                'getSessionId'
            ))
            ->getMock();

    $dp->expects($this->once())
        ->method('doesDirectoryExists')
        ->will($this->returnValue(TRUE));

    $dp->protectDirectory(TRUE);

}

}
```

Comment: I have used reflection to get access to the internal variables and functions, to ensure values are being set as I want, and the code expects to see. As others have stated, you do not need to test the private methods as they should be free to change over time, without impacting your code base, as long as your public methods remain unchanged.  I have tested the private methods though in our library code, to ensure the lower level library structures are built properly. Yes, when we change the structure, the tests will need to change, but we are OK with that trade off.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I suppose unit tests aren't really necessary for this class considering you can only create one real unit test to see if protectDirectory() is invoked.

Answer (score 5):

From https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

> **Limitation: final, private, and static methods**
>
> Please note that final, private and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked. They are ignored by PHPUnit's test double functionality and retain their original behavior.

Is not a good practice to unit test private or protected methods. You should test the public **API**. Private methods are supposed to be tested indirectly through the API. That said, you can make the method public with reflection:

```
$instance = new DirectoryProtector(...);

$ref = new \ReflectionClass('DirectoryProtector');

$method = $ref->getMethod('doesDirectoryExists');
$method->setAccessible(true);

$this->assertTrue($method->invoke($instance));
```

Comment: +1 for testing through the public API. I wouldn't resort to reflection if you have control over the class under test. Coupling your tests to the internals of a class (like private methods) leads to brittle tests that have to change every time you change the internal design of a class. That's something you want to minimise.

Comment: Testing the public API only allow you refactor your code (splitting methods, extrating new classes, ...) in the future without changing the behavior of your tested class.

Comment: Thanks for the response and comments. Considering this class will probably not be modified in the future, I thought I would make sure each private method was invoked properly. It doesn't really seem like I can do that. I suppose there isn't much use for including unit tests for this class. I have already included proper functional tests for the class though.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is incorrect. You shouldn't mock method, but objects that are passed by injection in constructor.

For the `SessionInterface` you can pass `MockArraySessionStorage`. For `ContainerInterface` I don't know which class you are using, so I add some demo example. Test case:

```
public function testProtectDirectory()
{
    $session = new MockArraySessionStorage();
    $session->setId('123123');
    $kernel = \Ouzo\Tests\Mock\Mock::create('ContainerInterface');
    \Ouzo\Tests\Mock\Mock::when($kernel)->getRootDir()->thenReturn('/root_dir');
    $directoryProtector = new DirectoryProtector($session, $kernel);

    $directoryProtector->protectDirectory(true);

    //asserts
}
```

and your methods will be returning:

`getViewableSessionDirectory` -> `/root_dir/../web/files/123123`

`getAppDir` -> `/root_dir`

And remember changing methods accessible is **always** bad idea.

PS. For [mocking I use utils form Ouzo framework](http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/documentation/tests.html#mocking). Of course you can use other mocking framework.